# Yii-Active Record return average result of a specific column as a string

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have a quick question. How do I use the MySQL AVG() query with Yii active record model and pass is as a string? This is how I query with my code now but it return to me as a NULL array...

```
/**
 * Gets topic average rating by comments
 * @param int $topic_id the topic unique id
 *
 * @return int rate
 */
public static function WS_countAverageRating($topic_id){
    return ExploreComment::model()->findAll(array('select'=>"AVG(rating)",'condition'=>"topic_id='".$topic_id."'"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is to do it with a statistical relationship.
Add something like this to your relations inside the model:

```
'avarageRating' => array(SELF::STAT, 'ExploreComment', 'topic_id', 'select' => 'AVG(rating)'),
```

Read more about statistical relations here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

Comment: hey mate... thanks for your assistance... i've manage to do it with your guide....